# CSS Pseudo-classes not working for main navigation links

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Code:

```
a:link { color: #111111; }
a:visited { color: #1b3a57; } 
a:hover { color: #f3371c; }
```

I have heaps of links on my site. And these states are working fine with, for example, the Footer text (links) and general body links. But the main navigation links and sub header links do not change state.

I have tested in IE 5+, Chrome, Opera, Safari, Maxthon, and FireFox but I get the same result.

What could cause this type of behaviour?

---

Update:

Header code:

```
#Header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;

    background-image: url('/Shared/Assets/Images/OrangeDot.png');
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;

}

    #Header #MainLogo {
        float: left;
    }
```

Sub Header code:

```
#SubHeader {
    width: 100%;
    height: max-content;
}
    #SubHeader ul {
        float: left;
        margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    }
        #SubHeader ul li img {
            line-height: 1.5em;
            margin: -.30em 0;
        }
        #SubHeader ul li {
            padding: 0 10px 0 10px;

        }
            #SubHeader ul li a {
                font-size: small;
                /*color: #f3371c;*/
            }
```

---

HTML Mark-up:

```
        <ul id="MainNavigation" class="HorizontalMenu WithBullets">
            <li><a class="HighlightedMenuOption" href="@Href("~/Home")">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Href("~/Protected/Account/")">Sign In | Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Support/")">Support</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/")">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/")">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="SubHeader">
        <div id="categories" class="s_nav">
            <ul>
              <li id="menu_home"> <a href="@Href("~/Home")">Home</a> </li>
              <li> <a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a>
                <div class="s_submenu">
                  <h3>Categories</h3>
                  <ul class="s_list_1 clearfix">
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <span class="clear border_eee"></span>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li> <a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a>
                <div class="s_submenu">
                  <h3>Categories</h3>
                  <ul class="s_list_1 clearfix">
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <span class="clear border_eee"></span>

                </div>
              </li>
              <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a>
                <div class="s_submenu">
                  <h3>Categories</h3>
                  <ul class="s_list_1 clearfix">
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <span class="clear border_eee"></span>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a>
                <div class="s_submenu">
                  <h3>Categories</h3>
                  <ul class="s_list_1 clearfix">
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <span class="clear border_eee"></span>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")">Tek Screws</a>
                <div class="s_submenu">
                  <h3>Categories</h3>
                  <ul class="s_list_1 clearfix">
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Shared/Products/")"></a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <span class="clear border_eee"></span>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

Comment: The HTML is syntactically valid, so I don't believe it has anything to do with my mark-up.

Comment: I've also tried clearing all Cache and Temp files in all browsers, and Refreshing, which hasn't helped.

Comment: Can you please share CSS of sub header and main navigation also?

Comment: Validate the site and maby you find some wrong spelled word somewhere http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: I've already validated my site, @Ziinloader.

Comment: I don't know why this got a down-vote. Anyway, @A.K - I have updated my question to include both Header and Sub Header CSS code.

Comment: My first question is why, and how are you testing on IE5? Is IE5 your main focus? If so, I am pretty sure IE5 doesn't know pseudo-classes (`:hover`). What does the HTML look like?

Comment: IE5 is the least of my concerns. I'm just saying that it is the earliest version that I have tested on. IE 9 and 10 are my main focus.

Comment: There is too much code to paste, but this is exactly the format of all navigation: `<ul id="Header"><li><a href="" title="">Some item</a></li></ul>` - And the same goes for SubHeader

Comment: Like I said, I doubt this will work on IE5, do you have an old Windows 98 box hanging out?   We really need to see the HTML

Comment: Ok, not a problem. I will post the HTML (but I need to remove it later on) - and I apologize if it's very long.

Comment: I've just added the HTML. I've removed the product names and descriptive text from the A tags in order to keep the code on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your HTML does not have a **DOCTYPE**  try adding it *.(Might Work ... !)*

As incorrect DOCTYPES lead to browser reverting to Quirks mode(IE) and CSS pseudo classes wont 
get along well with DOM in such scenario. For futher reading take a look at [doctype and css relation as seen in **alistapart.com**](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/)